# runOnUiThread in Presentation class

Tags: android, presentation

How can I update TextView in Presentation class if RunOnUiThread is not available in this class.

Here is my example

```
private final class DemoPresentation extends Presentation {

    public DemoPresentation(Context context, Display display) {
        super(context, display);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Be sure to call the super class.
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Inflate the layout.
        setContentView(R.layout.presentation_activity);
    }

    private void TimerMethod()
    {
        getAc.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `post()` on the `TextView`, passing in the same `Runnable` as you would to `runOnUiThread()`.